# Adapt sass to regular css

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

So I want to adapt this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tomaskuba/pen/NNeawR) into my page BUT it has bunch of dollar signs `selectors` that vscode underlines red, and it's not working. I came to understand the `$` are `SCSS` selector, but this is just a page I don't need another package installed. How can I remove or adapt the `SCSS` selectors to regular `CSS` selectors?

```
//----------------
$color-1: #0080dc;
$color-2: #ffffff;
$color-3: #323a45;
$color-4: #e6e6e6;
//----------------
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: color-3;
}
//----------------
.pricing-switcher {
  $bg-padding: 5px;
  $button-width: 150px;
  $button-height: 40px;
  $animation-time: 0.3s;

  text-align: center;

  .fieldset {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: $bg-padding;
    border-radius: 50em;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }

  input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  label {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: $button-width;
    height: $button-height;
    line-height: $button-height;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: $color-1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition: color $animation-time ease;
  }

  input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    color: $color-2;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .switch {
    /* floating background */
    position: absolute;
    top: $bg-padding;
    left: $bg-padding;
    height: $button-height;
    width: $button-width;
    background-color: $color-1;
    border-radius: 50em;
    transition: transform $animation-time;
  }

  input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .switch,
  input[type="radio"]:checked + label:nth-of-type(n) + .switch {
    /* use label:nth-of-type(n) to fix a bug on safari with multiple adjacent-sibling selectors*/
    -webkit-transform: translateX($button-width);
    -moz-transform: translateX($button-width);
    -ms-transform: translateX($button-width);
    -o-transform: translateX($button-width);
    transform: translateX($button-width);
  }
}
```

I tried deleting them but that did not work. DUHH! Is there a way to get regular CSS from this or how do I get it working?

Comment: in the css section there is a down arrow on the top right you will find an option to view compiled css

Comment: You beautiful human! Thanks it works.

Comment: Be aware that there is a syntax error in the `body` styles, I think the `color-3` is a reference to the variable `$color-3`, you might have to replace `color-3` with `#323a45` in the compiled CSS. 